# How to mock rabbit message to Spring StreamListener?

Tags: java, spring, junit, rabbitmq, spring-cloud

I want to, as part of a JUnit test, ensure that a `@StreamListener` method is being called through RabbitMQ.

I have a running project [here](https://github.com/joshua-yan/demo_listener_test) already, made just for this question (minimum reproducible) that has an empty JUnit test that I would like to make sure can hit my StreamListener method, and then something like verifying the autowired service was called. application.properties is set up.

I'll post some code here as well.

**DemoListener.java**

```
package com.example.demo.listeners;

import com.example.demo.dto.DemoDTO;
import com.example.demo.exchanges.DemoExchange;
import com.example.demo.service.DemoService;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.EnableBinding;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.StreamListener;

@EnableBinding(DemoExchange.class)
public class DemoListener {

    DemoService demoService;

    public DemoListener(DemoService demoService) {
        this.demoService = demoService;
    }

    @StreamListener(target = "demo_channel")
    public void consume(DemoDTO demoDTO) {
        this.demoService.log_params(demoDTO.getParam1(), demoDTO.getParam2(), demoDTO.getParam3());
    }
}
```

**DemoListenerTest.java**

```
package com.example.demo.listeners;

import com.example.demo.service.DemoService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DemoListenerTest {

    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "demo";

    private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "example.topic.exchange";

    private static final String ROUTING_KEY = "example.routing.key";

    @Autowired
    DemoService demoService;

    @Test
    public void test_consume(){
        //TODO how to trigger @StreamListener method during test and then verify that demoService was called once?
    }
}
```